# Securely shredding files

Tags: shell-script, data-destruction

Is the following a secure way of shredding files in *NIX systems:

**shredder.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Define number of rewrites
COUNT=20
# Define file size
FILE_SIZE=`wc -c < "$1"`
# Begin rewriting file
while [ $COUNT -ge 0 ]
do
   # Write random data to file
   echo `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count="$FILE_SIZE"` > $1
   COUNT=$(( $COUNT - 1 ))
done
```

Is the file being rewritten at the correct offset (starting point)?

Is there a shorter, better and more portable way of doing it?

Comment: Why not just use the built in `shred` program?

Comment: How secure is it? How many rewrites are done?

Comment: try `man shred`

Comment: I see it has a parameter for the number of iterations and a source for random bytes. But it doesn't mention the default source. Is it /dev/urandom?

Comment: It does not contain that, but it allows you to specify the source with `--random-source=`

Comment: This wouldn't work on a copy-on-write (COW) filesystem like btrfs or zfs.

Comment: Overwriting multiple times is generally not considered useful with post-90s harddrives, unless you need to conform to some old specification. @cas in that case, you should have your confidential files on a small partition+filesystem, which you then either intentionally drive into an out-of-space condition with a junk file filled from /dev/zero or /dev/urandom, or periodically overwrite as a partition.

Comment: Your script does not overwrite the file even once. And even if it did, it would not be secure.

Comment: @frostschutz Why? The contents are replaced with uniformly random generated bytes.

Comment: @rackandboneman a small partition+filesystem wouldnt help as wear leveling does not stop at partition bounderes

Comment: @Sebi because your script says: 1. set the file size to 0 and mark it's sectors for beeing available for reuse.
2. append random bytes to the file. As it does not specify the physical sector, the OS is free to write it to any free space.

Comment: @H. Idden true for solid state media.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not by a long mile.

What you're trying to do is impossible, so it isn't surprising that you're failing. The most egregious problem is that you aren't even attempting to overwrite the file: `… > $1` first truncates the file, which marks all of its blocks as free, and then the output of the command is written to newly-allocated blocks. There's no reason why the newly-allocated blocks would be the ones that were just allocated from the file.

If you ran `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count="$FILE_SIZE" of="$1"` then that would overcome this obstacle. You could be sure that you've overwritten this copy of the file. But other copies of the file could exist elsewhere, such as:

- Temporary copies created when the file was generated or edited.
- Older versions, if the file was edited in the past.
- Backups that might have been taken by anyone with access to the file.
- Other copies existing in a snapshot of the filesystem.
- Other copies that might have been made inside the storage device. On SSD, erasing is an expensive operation (both in terms of speed and in terms of wear on the device), so writing new content from a sector actually just [marks the sector as to be deleted later and writes the data in another sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling).

The secure way of erasing data is to have encrypted the whole disk from day 1. Then, to be sure that the data is unrecoverable, you only need to wipe the key, which is generally stored in a well-defined location. Preferably, don't store the actual key on the disk at all: if the machine boots with human intervention, use a strong passphrase; if the key boots without human intervention, store the key on a smartcard or on a cheap USB key or SD card that you can destroy physically without remorse.

Beware that as explained above, merely overwriting data on an SSD isn't guaranteed to make it unrecoverable if the attacker has hardware access or can hack the SSD's firmware. You need to use the SSD's secure erase functionality, assuming it has one that works (sadly, some SSD models purport to have the capability, but it doesn't actually wipe the data).

Answer (score 1):

Your script makes assumptions which are not necessarly true:

- Overwriting a part of a file will write the new data to the old sector
- This is especially not true for SSDs (look up wear leveling)
- You don't use a copy on write or overlay filesystem like btrfs or aufs

Edit: The above should only be considered a rough list of problems in your script. Allthough I am not fully ignorant at security questions there are many cases which are not handled here like temporary copies when editing your file, sending it to remote server, different caches, swap space, journals and many other things and things I don't know of.

Possible countermeasures (not (always) 100% secure):

- using shred, but is not intended for flash-based media like SSDs and not all filesystems including common ones like ext3
- using the tool from your SSD manufacturer, might not be available
- using full disk encryption before saving the file on it and also for the OS-partition, swap-partition, every other partition a (temporary) copy might be written and best also every other HDD/USB-stick/... . Back up all other data except the file you want to delete to an encrypted drive and then reformat and reencrypt all media having been in contact with the file (including the OS-partition) and put the other data back on the disk.

Comment: Psst!  The `man shred` mentioned in the comments to the question reveals a lot about the pitfalls, including the fact that **it does not surmount them**.

Comment: @JdeBP Clarified that it is not a full list but only examples where it will fail.

Comment: And yet the answer _still_ tells readers that `shred` is a countermeasure for such problems when the command's own manual tells you that **it is not**.

Comment: @JdeBP thanks, when I learned about shred I was told it would especially take care about this ...