# how to delete a file physically from disk in linux so that there is no way it can be recovered?

Tags: data-recovery, delete, deleted-files

I am trying to delete a file in linux, (Ubuntu 20.04). As per my understanding, when we delete a file, the inode and directory entry structures are modified first and the file is actually deleted at a later time. This is one of the reasons why the file can be recovered by different tools later.

I want to delete a file and know that it has been physically deleted from the disk.
There should be no way that I can retrieve it at any point of time.

Comment: `shred` is your friend

Comment: @Panki not on an SSD it's not. Wear levelling may mean new sectors get allocated rather than old ones being overwritten

Comment: Looking at the "caution" section in `man shred`, it also doesn't promise to work with journaling filesystems, which is… pretty much all of them, these days? I guess you could delete the file and then `dd if=/dev/random of=fillthedisk; rm fillthedist` which should fill most space available to files, likely including the old file contents, with randomness.

Comment: This can be done with [BleachBit](https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/command-line-interface.html#:~:text=Linux%20Running%20bleachbit%20%28which%20is%20in%20the%20path%29,generally%20not%20available%20over%20SSH%20or%20in%20cron%29.). *$ bleachbit --shred /path/to/file*

Comment: Rather than shred the whole empty area of the disk, you might just find the block count of the file and use `dd -i  /dev/zero` to kill the data `before` you rm it. Not sure why random junk is any harder to recover the data from than zeroes. Special care may be needed for huge sparse files.

Comment: You'll find several Q/As about this topic here on U&L. For instance, these look relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63424/315749, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245999/315749